# How do I get the "changes" (commit message) that triggered a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

I can go to

```
http://myjenkins:8080/job/Project/42/changes
```

and see the commit message that triggered a particular Jenkins build.

However, I want to grab this via REST API or something. I'm not having any luck in search. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get the comment, affected files and commit ID from a Jenkins build:

```
curl http://jenkins/job/JOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?pretty=true&tree=changeSet[items[comment,affectedPaths,commitId]]
```

Here's an [explanation of how the tree and depth parameters work](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/05/taming-jenkins-json-api-with-depth-and.html).

Comment: @gareth_bowles: This worked for me. But It did not display the commit message which we enter. We use TortoiseSVN client. Commit Id and files affected are displaying fine. But not the commit message which I see when accessing http://jenkins:8080/job/Project/42/changes in browser.

Comment: @gareth_bowles: The field 'msg' gave me the detail I wanted. Thanks. For me the URL was: curl http://jenkins/job/JOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?pretty=true&tree=changeSet[items[msg,affectedPaths,commitId]]

Comment: should be changeSet"s" not changeSet.

Answer (score 0):

These information can be extracted as well from api

```
api/json?tree=actions[parameters[*],lastBuiltRevision[branch[*]],tags[*]],artifacts[fileName],changeSet[items[msg,comment,commitId,author[fullName],paths[*]]]
```

You can always look at the `[*]` and extract what you want too