# How to handle monolithic project in one root in jenkins with gradle?

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am maintaining a monolithic repository which have multiple projects and those projects may depend or not each other. Those projects should not have a common build script file.

```
Root_Project
         ├─ ProjectA
         │   └─├─ libs
         │     ├─ src
         │     └─ build.gradle
         ├─ ProjectB                 
         │     ├─ libs
         │     ├─ src
         │     └─ build.gradle
```

I want to connect root project to **Jenkins** CI server. I want to do is trigger the update of any project and build only that project in Jenkins server. That mean if someone commit to ProjectA, Jenkins should only trigger the update and build only ProjectA build script.

Does anybody have any idea to do this ?

Comment: Does root project contain build.gradle? Is there a settings.gradle file?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking No. it should not contain any file

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this is like this:

1. get the list of changes files that caused the build (`curl http://jenkins/job/JOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?pretty=true&tree=changeSet[items[affectedPaths]]` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170892/how-do-i-get-the-changes-commit-message-that-triggered-a-jenkins-build) answer)
2. parse the path of the files to see which project(s) the changes affect
3. run only the gradle builds for those specific projects